# Force to use https instead of http with spring-ws

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

How will you force http connection to use https when clients try to connect to the server using spring-ws? I have seen some examples that uses WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but what is the best way of doing it for annotation based (No XML configuration file exists) spring-ws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I ended up using Spring EndpointInterceptors to accomplish this. Here is one example I referred to:http://spring-webservice-2-step-by-step.blogspot.com/2011/12/spring-web-services-20-step-by-step.html

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the container you're running Spring-WS in. For instance, in Tomcat, you have to put a [security constraint](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=104951559722619&w=2) in your `web.xml`.